# How did I lose rep when an answer of mine was deleted which had no upvotes?

Tags: support, deleted-answers

I recently lost 13 reputation

```
-13  18:30  removed Is it ok to “make up ” your resume?
```

when [this answer](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/a/10774/2322) was deleted by community on The Workplace.

The answer is currently at +0/-1 so I am a bit confused where the -13 comes from.

But it's also not at the top of the answers anymore (the bottom, actually, guess that's what happens on April Fools day questions...) but the answer list is sorted by vote count.

---

It seems *possible* the answer was actually accepted and that when the question was deleted it was automatically unaccepted (-15 + 2 = -13), but if I remember right, when a question is unaccepted it shows as "unaccept" for the rep reason (not just "removed").

Or, are answers automatically unaccepted and this rep penalty rolled into the total if the question is deleted?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When an accepted answer gets deleted, the checkmark disappears from the interface*.

But internally it's "still there". So "-13 removed" is correct and you should not be seeing "unaccept".

*Some accepted answers that were deleted before a certain point kept their checkmarks on the interface. But that was a while ago.

Comment: Hmm. I think I was/am confused because the answers become sorted by vote count (irrespective of whether it's accepted or not).

Comment: @enderland Deletion disables the accepted answer sorting. This has always been the case even before they started removing the checkmarks upon deletion.

Comment: Hmm, I guess you learn things every day :)